# Load The Facebook Comments with a click using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-comments

I do not know much of javascript and my English is not very good .
Could someone help me to load the facebook comment box with single click using javascript ( jquery not ) .

I found an alterative to load the comment box type Lazy Load.

```
<script>
function loadAPI() {
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID&version=v2.0';
    document.body.appendChild(js);
}

window.onscroll = function () {
    var rect = document.getElementById('comments').getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top < window.innerHeight) {
        loadAPI();
        window.onscroll = null;
    } 
}
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div id="comments" class="fb-comments" data-href="YOUR_WEBPAGE" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

But desire, the same procedure by clicking on a label `<a> View comments </a>` and clicking on the charge the comment box in the id = "comments"

If anyone can help me I thank you very much

Comment: You want to add the Facebook Comments plugin to the URL dynamically, after the rest of the HTML has already loaded? what issue are you encountering, exactly? that's possible, you just need to call [XFBML.parse()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) in the JS SDK and it should replace new XFBML tags (e.g. fb:comments) you've added dynamically 
That works for the JS version of the plugin, not sure if it's different with the HTML5 version